# Transaction Outbox Pattern with AWS Aurora Postgres and aws_lambda.invoke

Tags: postgresql, microservices, amazon-aurora, outbox-pattern

I am working on a project which is made out of a couple of microservices. I am planning to use Transaction Outbox Pattern by calling a lambda function in Postgres after insert trigger.

I am thinking something like this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tx_msg_func()    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE newRecord JSON;
BEGIN
    newRecord :=  row_to_json(NEW.*);

    PERFORM * FROM aws_lambda.invoke(
        aws_commons.create_lambda_function_arn('my_lambda_function'),
        newRecord,
        'Event'
    );

    RETURN NEW;
END;

$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER tx_msg_insert AFTER INSERT ON tx_outbox_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tx_msg_func();
```

Here, the lambda function will receive the new record as JSON and will send an SQS message. After sending the message successfully, it will delete the record from `tx_outbox_table`

I am wondering if there is any downside here that I am missing. Do you think this is a production-ready solution? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: Did you end up going with this solution, @optimus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what about transaction? It should be as short as possible. After insert is executed inside transaction, so... TCP call goes inside the transaction. What can be done with it? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727335/after-insert-trigger-in-separate-transaction) is an idea. Exceptions are processed outside current transaction. New transaction is lighter when nothing is written, so maybe that is the way to go?

Comment: So what you are saying is, if the TCP call fails, the whole transaction will roll back, am I right? If that's the case, then it is all good because committing to the db and calling the lambda MUST happen, if either one fails, both should fail.

Comment: also if something goes wrong transaction will hang until timeout...